# PL/SQL: TO_CHAR show format

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

So I have this code here:

```
create or replace FUNCTION calc_length(
  START_TIME  IN number, 
  FINISH_TIME IN number
) RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  RETURN  ( (FINISH_TIME - START_TIME )   ;
END
```

And I want to show the result in the format as `H:mm`

I tried `TO_CHAR` function but it accepts a strict preset formats.

Comment: What is the initial time precision? Are those start_time and end_time are being passed in to your procedure as hours or minutes or seconds, or maybe days? As soon as you decided on time precision, the arithmetic would be quite trivial. Besides, why not use values of `date` or `timestamp` data type?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov lets say the start time is 1205 and the end time is 1355 so that will give me a difference of 150 which will stand for 1h50m

Comment: Interesting. You didn't answer my question though about what those values of `start_time` and `end_time` represent. But from your example it looks like number 1355 is 13 hours 55 minutes and 1205 is 12 hours 05 minutes. The question is shouldn't the difference between `end_time` and `start_time` in this situation be 1 hour and 30 minutes instead of 1 hour and 50 minutes? Otherwise.... strange arithmetic.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov My appologies! The values are in `NUMBER` format so `1215` stands for 12:15 and `1355` stands for 13:55. Question is if i multiply the result of `end-time - start_time` by `0.01` so i get the time in the format `Hours.Minutes` how would i split the value before the values between the decimal point so if i get `2.25` i split them into `2` and `25`

Answer (score 1):

Few examples - copy, paste to see the oputput:

```
SELECT trunc(mydate / 3600) hr
     , trunc(mod(mydate, 3600) / 60) mnt
     , trunc(mod(mydate, 3600) / 60 /60) sec
 FROM 
 (
  SELECT (to_date('01/02/2013 23:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy  hh24:mi:ss') -
          to_date('01/01/2013 07:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy  hh24:mi:ss')) * 86400 mydate
    FROM dual
 )
 /

 Select hh, mi, ss From
 (
  Select EXTRACT(hour   From Cast(SYSDATE as timestamp)) hh,
         EXTRACT(minute From Cast(SYSDATE as timestamp)) mi,
         EXTRACT(second From Cast(SYSDATE as timestamp)) ss
   From dual
  )
  /

Select start_date, end_date, time_diff,
   EXTRACT(DAY FROM time_diff) days,
   EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time_diff) hours,
   EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM time_diff) minutes,
   EXTRACT(SECOND FROM time_diff) seconds
  From
  (
   Select start_date, end_date, end_date - start_date time_diff
     From
      (
       Select CAST(to_date('21/02/2012 06:10:53 am', 'dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mi:ss am') AS TIMESTAMP) end_date
            , CAST(to_date('21/02/2012 12:05:00 am', 'dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mi:ss am') AS TIMESTAMP) start_date
     From dual
      ))
     /
```